# Init script won't "stop" forked C program

Tags: linux, init, raspbian

I have a C program what has a "daemon" mode, so that I can have it run in the background. When it is run with "-d" it forks using the following code:

```
if(daemon_mode == 1)
{
    int i = fork();
    if(i<0) exit(1); // error
    if(i>0) exit(0); // parent
}
```

I created an init script, and when i manually run the init script to start my daemon, it starts ok, however, if i run it with "stop" the daemon isn't stopped.

I imagine the issue is that the PID has changed due to forking, what am I don't wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: `fork` returns a `pid_t`, not an `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Is that pid_t of use to solving my problem?

Comment: No, using `pid_t` will have almost no bearing on anything!

Comment: You should call `daemon(3)`, not just once `fork(2)`, in daemon mode.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look into daemon(3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a pid file to control the process, then you are likely correct that changing the pid is causing a problem.  Just write the pid file after you have daemonized rather than before.

Comment: Actually, I'm not explicitly doing anything pid file related myself, I assumed the init script was handling that, I@m using the basic skeleton init script.

Comment: Ok, I tried creating the PID file myself, which worked when running with sudo but as soon as I moved the binary to /usr/sbin and chowned it to root.root then setuid root on it, the file creation for the pid file keeps giving me a file not found for some reason (i'm trying to create it at "/var/run/myappname.pid"